# How to implement a default operator<<(ostream&, T) for type without this operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

Since `std::to_string` is added to c++11, I started implementing `to_string` instead of the more traditional `operator<<(ostream&, T)`.  I need to link the two together in order to incorporate libraries that rely on `operator<<(ostream&, T)`.  I want to be able to express that if T has `operator<<(ostream&, T)`, use it; otherwise, use `std::to_string`.  I am prototyping a more limited version that enables `operator<<` for all enum classes.

```
enum class MyEnum { A, B, C };

// plain version works
//std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyEnum& t) {
//  return (out << to_string(t));
//}

// templated version not working
template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type
>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& t) {
  return (out << to_string(t));
}
```

Compiler says `error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'MyEnum')
  cout << v << endl;`

Questions:

1. Why is the template function not found by the compiler?
2. Is there a way to implement the general solution?

Comment: You really [shouldn't extend `std`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

Comment: @Polikdir Not sure about this.  For example, boost Test requires ostream& std::operator<<(ostream&, T) to work.

Comment: @CandyChiu the operator doesnt need to be in namespace std for that to work.

Comment: I fear you can't just do `std::to_string(t)`, where `t` is of type `MyEnum`. At least, clang-703.0.31 says it couldn't find such a `std::to_string` that accepted a `const MyEnum`.

Comment: You are not using `std::enable_if` correctly. Don't add it to temolate parameters. Instead, wrap the return type in it.

Comment: @ForceBru the plain version is the implementation.  the question is how do I turn it into the template version.

Comment: @n.m. return type is ostream&, don't think I can change that.

Comment: You cannot implement std::to_string for user-defined types, so the utility of it all is unclear.

Comment: You are not supposed to change it. Pass ostream as the second argument to std::enable_if. Note that `enable_if<true,T>::type` is `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work if there exists a `std::to_string` that accepts an argument of type `const MyEnum` (which *doesn't exist* according to clang-703.0.31).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class MyEnum { A, B, C };

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::ostream &>::type
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& t) {
    return (out << std::to_string(t));
}

int main() {
  MyEnum a;

  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

According to the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/), there are two ways of using `std::enable_if`, one of which is to *make the return type of a function only valid if `T` is an enum type* (in your case). This is what this code shows. If `std::is_enum<T>::value` is `true`, then `std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::ostream &>::type` results in `std::ostream &` and is not defined (which makes the compiler yell at you) otherwise.

You could <strike>probably</strike> write something like `my::to_string` which would try to convert to a string user-defined types as well:

```
namespace my {

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<! std::is_void<T>{} && std::is_fundamental<T>{}, std::string>::type
    to_string(T t) {
        return std::to_string(t);
    }

    std::string to_string(std::nullptr_t) = delete;

    std::string to_string(MyEnum a) {
        return "This is an enum";
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `my::to_string` instead of `std::to_string` in your `operator<<`:

```
return (out << my::to_string(t));
```

**EDIT:** using `my::to_string` now results in a compilation error when it's argument is `void` or `std::nullptr_t`.

---

### Why your code didn't work

Look at the example in the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/):

> ```
> // 2. the second template argument is only valid if T is an integral type:
> template < class T,
>        class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
> bool is_even (T i) {return !bool(i%2);}
> ```

As you can see, the second template argument is written with `class = /* enable_if stuff */`, but in your code you do simply `template< typename T, /* enable_if stuff */ >`. So, if you follow the docs, you'll get the correct result - the compiler will say it couldn't find a specialization of `std::to_string` that accepted an `enum` as a parameter.

Comment: this works, thanks.  Scott Meyer (also another SOF post) recommended the enable_if hack best appears as a template argument (as opposed to return type or function argument), would you explain why my approach didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.